# Installing magento CE 1.9 on AWS

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, database, amazon-web-services, aws

I want to install Magento CE 1.9.X on Amazon AWS (CentOS). I am new to it.

I do not want to use AMI.

Could you point me to a step by step guide please?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't come across this yet, it should be of use: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-quick-start-magento-for-e-commerce/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I saw and it uses AWS CloudFormation  template which creates load balancer with 2 apache nodes etc. I am looking for a single instance of apache/mysql(RDS)/S3. Do you know of guide that does this way please?

Answer (score 0):

LEMP stack:

1 - startup any instance with this `CentOS 7` image:
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW

2 - login to your instance, and upload this script:

```
cd
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magenx/Magento-Automated-Server-Configuration-from-MagenX/master/Magento/CentOS-7/MASC-M-7.sh
```

3 - run this script: `bash MASC-M-7.sh`

4 - follow onscreen instructions.

thats it.

PS

> if you need a bit different apache stack - https://bitnami.com/stack/magento